# Stochastic processes understanding of probabilty measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain $\{X_n,n \geq 0\}$ with finite state space $S = \{1,2,\ldots ,m\}$ and transition probability matrix $P = (P_{ij})_{i,j\in S}$.
Let $P_{ij}^n$ be the probability that the process in state $i$ is in state $j$ after $n$ transitions.
Suppose that for any $i,j \in S$, the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} P_{ij}^n = \pi_j > 0$ exists and is independent of $i$. Prove that the probability measure $\pi = (\pi_1, \pi_2, \ldots, \pi_m)$ satisfies $\pi P = \pi$.
By Chapman Kolmogorov I proved that $\pi_j= \sum_{i=1}^m P_{ij}^k \pi_i$ but am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: By chapman kolmogorov ive proved π(j)= Σ(i=1 to m) P(ij)k π(i) but am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I recommend reading [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), especially the parts about providing context and typesetting.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to note that
$$
(\pi P)(j) = 
\sum_{k=1}^m \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} P_{ik}^n\right) P_{kj} = 
\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^mP_{ik}^nP_{kj}\right) = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} P^{n+1}_{ij} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} P^{n}_{ij} = \pi(j).
$$

Comment: How would you prove that the probability measure $\pi$ is the unique probability measure satisfying $\pi P=\pi$?

Comment: @math647382 there is no way to do so for this question; note in particular that $\pi$ might fail to be unique if the Markov chain is reducible. If you're really interested in how to prove that (with the proper assumptions on the Markov chain), I suggest you post a new question.